# Safely query SQL table with variable table name

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to make some common code for retrieving identities from tables and that involves making an unsafe query string to inject the table name.

I read everywhere that I cannot safely inject the table name. So I want to query if the table exists, then based on the result, perform a real or dummy query.

```
var unsafeTableQuery = "SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[" + tableName + "] WHERE [BulkInsertSessionID] = @bulkInsertSessionId";
var guardQuery =
"DECLARE @Exists BIT = ( SELECT CAST( COUNT(1) AS BIT ) FROM sys.tables WHERE name = @TableName AND type = 'U' );" +
"IF (@Exists = 0) SELECT TOP 0 NULL 'Id'" +
"ELSE " + unsafeTableQuery;
var cmd = new SqlCommand(guardQuery, conn, tran);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TableName", tableName));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@bulkInsertSessionId", bulkInsertSessionId));

using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    int index = 0;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int id = (int)reader[0];
        entities[index++].Id = id;
    }
}
```

Even though I have an unsafe concatenation, I'm first querying the table name against the `sys.tables` by a parameter. And if it doesn't exist, the `IF..ELSE` block will never step into the unsafe query.

For easier readability I'm expecting to run the following query:

```
DECLARE @Exists BIT = ( SELECT CAST( COUNT(1) AS BIT ) FROM sys.tables WHERE name = @TableName AND type = 'U' );
IF(@Exists = 0)
SELECT TOP 0  NULL 'Id'
ELSE
SELECT [Id] from <InjectedTableName> where BulkInsertSessionID = @bulkSessionId
```

Am I correct in my assumption that this is safe?

Comment: `tableName = "Users]; drop table users;--"`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri and where does this get executed?

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteReader()` ?

Comment: It will evaluate to:

`ELSE
SELECT [Id] from [dbo].[Users]; drop table users-- where BulkInsertSessionID = @bulkSessionId` It will successfully select and then drop your table

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri
 
 `declare @bulkSessionId int = 1
 DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100) = 'Users; drop table users;--';
 DECLARE @Exists BIT = ( SELECT CAST( COUNT(1) AS BIT ) FROM sys.tables WHERE name = @TableName AND type = 'U' );
 IF(@Exists = 0)
 SELECT TOP 0  NULL 'Id'
 ELSE
 SELECT 'This will not execute'`

Comment: I will post as an answer..

Comment: If you must do dynamic sql like this at least make sure you use [QUOTENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your users have an access to change the variable `tableName`. I suppose some user types it on some form. Suppose he types this:

```
Users]; DROP TABLE Users;--
```

Then your whole command will be:

```
DECLARE @Exists BIT = ( SELECT CAST( COUNT(1) AS BIT ) FROM sys.tables WHERE name = @TableName AND type = 'U' );
IF(@Exists = 0)
SELECT TOP 0  NULL 'Id'
ELSE
SELECT [Id] from [Users]; DROP TABLE Users;-- where BulkInsertSessionID = @bulkSessionId
```

This will do its `IF ELSE` part and then will go to next statement which is:

```
DROP TABLE Users;
```

Note that drop statement will execute in any case even if `ELSE` part is not executed, because you don't have `BEGIN END`. Note that the rest is commented out... This is most basic injection method...

Comment: After putting a `BEGIN..END` for the `ELSE` block, I ran the query generation which produced the following: 

`DECLARE @Exists BIT = ( SELECT CAST( COUNT(1) AS BIT ) FROM sys.tables WHERE name = @TableName AND type = 'U' );IF (@Exists = 0) SELECT TOP 0 NULL 'Id' ELSE BEGIN SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[StatusTime; DROP TABLE Temp;--] WHERE [BulkInsertSessionID] = @bulkInsertSessionId END` (and adding the necessary parameters), the Temp table that I created for this exercise was not dropped.

What now?

Comment: @romeozor, so do you want to say that you believe that code is safe? It is your decision but It is not safe. It was not dropped because it probably thrown an exception. Just try this: `Users]; END DROP TABLE Users;--`

Comment: I'm not saying anything, I'm asking for help. I tried it with your previous comment and it still didn't drop the table. 

I'm willing to accept that it's not safe, but you being passive-aggressive about it is not helping.

Comment: I am not agressive at all. Do you get any exceptions? I just checked on my database and it drops the table... Can you add a breakpoint to your using statement and see what is `unsafeTableQuery` and copy here?